# Reported speech. Talking about the past, present and future in one sentence

Tags: reported-speech

I've tried to come up with some sentences to exercise my skill in reported speech. I've been wondering if they all seem correct and natural to native speakers. I also wonder which is considered the most correct and the purist version of the language, i.e. the best practice for which I could get a good grade on some formal exam.

**The original direct speech on which I base all the following reported speech:**

> "I was studying all day long yesterday, I am working now and tomorrow
> I will go to the hospital."

**Reported speech - version 1:**

> He explained that *he had been studying* all day long *yesterday*, *was*
> working *now*, and *would* go to the hospital *tomorrow*."

(The mentioned *yesterday*, *now* and *tomorrow* are all related to the present moment.)

**Reported speech - version 2:**

An alternative version with supposedly the same meaning as the one above:

> "He explained that he *was* working all day long *yesterday*, *is* working
> *now*, and *will* go to the hospital *tomorrow*."

**Reported speech - version 3:**

> He explained that he *had been* studying all day long *the day before (=the previous day)*,
> *was* working *then*, and *would* go to the hospital *the next day (=the
> following day)*.

**UPDATE:**

It seems the correct way to convert it into reported speech would be:

> He explained that he was working all day yesterday, was working now,
> and would go to the hospital tomorrow.

My reasoning:

"I was working all day **yesterday**." - He said he was working all day yesterday. ("yesterday" is still "yesterday", the simple past and "yesterday" remain unchanged.)

Although I'm not sure if it's interchangeable with this in the given context: He said he **had been** working all day **yesterday**?

"I am working **now**." - He said he was working **now**.  ("now" is still "now" or rather it's synonymous to the present moment)
But I'm in doubt about the word **now**. Is it interchangeable with **then** in this context?

"I will go to the hospital **tomorrow**." - He said he **would** go to the hospital **tomorrow**. ("tomorrow" is still in the future)

Comment: Version #2 is invalid because of ***is*** and ***will***. There's nothing wrong with using ***was*** instead of ***had been*** for the initial "Past within the Past" reference; it's just that we'd *usually* use the Perfect form there. Note that we usually use ***then*** for this kind of Past reference, but ***now*** is acceptable. But you can't use ***yesterday*** to mean ***the day before*** here, so that one depends entirely on whether it really ***is*** still "yesterday".

Comment: #2 seems fine to me, so long as *now* is understood to cover the time he said it and the time the current speaker is reporting it (i.e. he's still working at the moment). And "the day before" sounds right in version 3 too, it matches "the next day" and implies the speaker didn't say this today (otherwise it would sound a little weird). "Was working **then**" feels like it's still talking about "the day before" though, to me - I'd prefer something like "was currently working" to make the change of time frame more explicit, or "right then", if you really don't want to reuse "now"!

Comment: If you are studying for a formal exam they can expect you to show the conversion like you did in #3 and can frown at the lack of time conversion in #1. The #2 will likely be considered invalid.

Comment: @AlexeiRayu: Sounds like you've done those kind of formal exams yourself! Excellent brief summary!

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I've done some further research and has come to this version: "He said he was studying all day yesterday, was working now, and would go to the hospital tomorrow"

Comment: I'd probably prefer *He said he **had been** studying all day yesterday* (or ***the day before*** if following ***now*** actually means ***then*** rather than "current time of utterance" for "**He said...**"). But it's really a stylistic choice.

Comment: I'm with @cactustictacs - #2 is fine as long as the time indicators still apply (ie. it's correct if it's still the same day and he's still working). In general, backshifting isn't that necessary unless something (including the time indicators - eg. "today" to "the day before") has changed between the time of the original statement and the time of reporting, although a formal exam will probably indeed expect #3 because it shows the changes that *can* happen under reported speech.

Comment: (eg. "I want to go bowling." "What did he say?" "He said he wants to go bowling" - it's a reasonable assumption that if you just repeated what the other person said, the statement they made is still true in the present).

Comment: I'll add more context: #1 "I met him earlier today and he told me that he had been studying all day yesterday, was working now (or then), and would go to the hospital tomorrow. #2" I met him last week and he told me that he had been studying the day before, was working then, and would go to the hospital the next day. "